# How to solve these differential equations?

Tags: matlab, ode

I am working on a heat exchanger and found these differential equations from a paper. I never had such equation as you can see even if it's a single order differential equation a term "dy" is always hanging at right side of the equation.

I am trying to solve them in matlab but due to dy, I am not able to put it into an equation.

Can anyone help me to simplify the equation or any help on how such type of equations can be solved in matlab?

These are the equations:

[image: These are the equations]

Comment: You can solve these equations numerically with finite differences schemes.

Comment: but what about that hanging "dy" ?? If finite differences method can solve it, please let me know any source/example where I can find the similar equation solved.

Comment: As this has something to do with heat transport, one would expect the Laplace operator involved. Check if this is only a typographical error, wrong font, as `dy` would be really `\Delta y`.

Comment: I too though it might be the typo when I looked at 1st equation but it's again present in 2nd equation.

Comment: One way you could (possibly) approach this is by dividing your first equation by *dy* such that you obtain *(dT)/(dxdy)*. Now you discretize this expression and solve equation(1). (Please not that this can depend on youf functions T,U,...).

Comment: This way you obtain the Laplacian.
(You could take a look at this about when to move dx (in the ODE case): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673980/what-can-we-move-dx-around-and-integrate-both-sides-when-solving-ode)

Comment: Can you post what paper it is? I've never seen something like this.

Comment: Did my approach help?

Comment: @StefanM sorry but I am not able to slove it that way. Maybe my lack of knowledge in Maths is the reason. What I know is, if we have dxdy in denominator, the numerator should be d^2T. isn't it? If not, please let me have some reference to study this kind of equations where dT/dxdy can be solved.

Comment: @user1543042 http://www.sid.ir/en/VEWSSID/J_pdf/102420090202.pdf here, equation 19, 20, 21, 22

I am not able to solve any of these!!

Comment: Dividing in this case meant taking the derivative with respect to y. I called it dividing because often you can treat d/dx (etc.) as a fraction.

Comment: You interpret the right hand side of your first equation as: RHS = f(x,y)dy.
And then you take the derivative with respect to y of both sides and obtain:
Laplacian of T equals d/dy RHS

Comment: Deriving your RHS could look like that: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+(x%2B1)+dx

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Eqs (23) and (24). They specify the definitions of \dot{m}_p and \dot{m}_s so that when you plug them into Eqs (19) and (20) they lose the floating differentials.

Comment: unbelievable!! How I missed that!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: anyway to solve equation 21 and 22? I am using matlab but not sure how to code such complex ODEs.

Comment: The structure of that paper is terrible. And I don't see a definition for \dot{m}_w... You might want to ask that to the community. Once you regularize the equations